# nicematrix \ddots has different performances in different documentclass

Tags: matrices, document-classes, nicematrix

When I use \documentclass{article}, just like (no problem)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent,nullify-dots}

\newcommand{\underbracedmatrix}[2]{%
    \left(\;
    \smash[b]{\underbrace{
            \begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width = auto]#1\end{NiceMatrix}
        }_{#2}}
    \;\right)
    \vphantom{\underbrace{\begin{NiceMatrix}#1\end{NiceMatrix}}_{#2}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
K=
\underbracedmatrix{
    3  & 1 &      &      &   \\
    1  & 2 &  1   &      &   \\
    & 1 &\ddots&\ddots&   \\
    &   &\ddots&  3   & 1 \\
    &   &      &  1   & 1 \\}{n}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I use \documentclass{revtex4-1}, it just like

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent,nullify-dots}

\newcommand{\underbracedmatrix}[2]{%
    \left(\;
    \smash[b]{\underbrace{
            \begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width = auto]#1\end{NiceMatrix}
        }_{#2}}
    \;\right)
    \vphantom{\underbrace{\begin{NiceMatrix}#1\end{NiceMatrix}}_{#2}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
K=
\underbracedmatrix{
    3  & 1 &      &      &   \\
    1  & 2 &  1   &      &   \\
    & 1 &\ddots&\ddots&   \\
    &   &\ddots&  3   & 1 \\
    &   &      &  1   & 1 \\}{n}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]
I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! Where is available document class `vertex4-1`? prob ably it should be `revtex4-1` . With this package the result is as you reported.

Comment: @Zarko Oh, my mistake! Yes, It is 'revtex4-1', but the problem still exists.

Comment: I will try to find a solution to this problem (I wrote the extension `nicematrix`).

Comment: @F.Pantigny Thanks a lot! The new version (2.1.5 2019-05-27) works well on `revtex4-1` and `revtex4-2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have written a new version of `nicematrix` to solve this problem. The new version (2.1.5 2019-05-27) is now compatible with the classes `revtex4-1` and `revtex4-2`.